# How to use reverse Google GeoCoding in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

i am newbie in iOS Development. i use Google Map sdk for get Location From MapView. i Got Current Location Like as Latitude and Longitude but now i want to get Current Address with Zip code From latitude and longitude, How it Possible please give me Solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CLGeocoder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html) and the [`reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:) method :

```
- (void)getAddressFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location completionHandler:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *placemark))completionHandler failureHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureHandler
{
    NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
         if (failureHandler && (error || placemarks.count == 0)) {
             failureHandler(error);
         } else {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             if(completionHandler) {
                 completionHandler(placemark.addressDictionary);
             }
         }
    }];
}
```

And call it like that :

```
// Your location from latitude and longitude
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:aLatitude longitude:aLongitude];

// Call the method to find the address
[self getAddressFromLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSMutableDictionary *d) {
     NSLog(@"address informations : %@", d);
     NSLog(@"formatted address : %@", [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]);
     NSLog(@"Street : %@", [d valueForKey:@"Street"]);
     NSLog(@"ZIP code : %@", [d valueForKey:@"ZIP"]);
     NSLog(@"City : %@", [d valueForKey:@"City"]);
     // etc.
 } failureHandler:^(NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
 }];
```

Comment: I want to Fetch Only Some data From This addressDictionary like as CityName,Address, Street adesss,Zipcode,Etc how to fetch it?

Comment: The MKPlacemark object has an `addressDictionary` which you are able to access via `valueForKey`: 

NSArray *shortDescArray = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];

Answer (score 0):

You could use CLGeocoder:

```
__block CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init]; 

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:theLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            DDLogVerbose(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);

            if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(geocodeFailed:)]) {
                [self.delegate geocodeFailed:error];
            }

            return;
        }

        MKPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

        if(placemark) {

            NSArray *shortDescArray = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];
            NSString *shortDesc = [shortDescArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

            DDLogVerbose(@"myPlacemark %@", placemark.addressDictionary);
        } else {
            DDLogVerbose(@"Geocode failed");
        }
    }];
```